# Force Chrome to always fetch javascript files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

If I have an UI view in view.js and open that one in chrome the script gets downloaded and cached (view.js doesn't get downloaded on second visit) DESPITE having cache disabled (in dev tools, cache killer, whatever I'm using). 
If I work with the editor of dev tools, change something and save it (editor background turns red) I can open view.js again and the changes were made because Chrome uses the edited view.js.

How can I force Chrome to always download the js files so I can change my files in Eclipse, save them and the changes appear on re-opening view.js. I don't want to reload the whole page, just want to re-open the view.

I hope it is specific enough.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413243/1374307) or this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4206224/1374307)

Comment: This edits the behaviour of js files, not Chrome. I want to force Chrome to not cache globally.

Comment: yes, am sorry, I didn't read the question completely. But there is a similar question in SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11029726/1374307), which also suggests the my previous comment answer. The `Ctrl+R` works for me in chrome, but is not a permanent solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add to filename some randome has ( for example timestamp ) - on every load of page url become unique - thus cache would be disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can tell browsers that you want them to prefer the current (online) version of the files. You can also tell them that you want all the files not included in the manifest to be downloaded from the server.

```
SETTINGS:
prefer-online
NETWORK:
*
```