# Mozilla do NOT update source code

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-cache

I'm developing a website.

I test it in Mozilla,
When I make a change to the website javascript code, I find that the change is not reflected in the browser(I checked code in debugger of Mozilla)

I understand that it's a cache problem because when I clear cache, the things work properly.

Have I identified the issue correctly?
If yes, is there a way to get rid of Clearing Cache every time?

Comment: You can temporarily disable caching or press `cmd`+`shift`+`r` to reload without using the cache.

Comment: This is a question about the use of Mozilla Firefox, and is more appropriate on SuperUser.SE.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I disagree. It is related to a crucial step in web development. Similar questions about development tools have been asked and answered on SO without any problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable JavaScript caching in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029726/disable-javascript-caching-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @str, I understand that u r talking about mac, what will be equivalent in other laptops(windows, ubuntu)?

Comment: Probably `ctrl`+`shift`+`r`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the tools (F12). Go to `Preferences` > `Advanced Parameters` > `Disable cache (when dev tool is open)`.

This way you only disable cache in dev mode, and have no impact on other sites navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You have an option to disable caching in `Preferences`.
Go to `Preferences->Advanced -> Network` and check `Override automatic cache management`.
Limit it to`0`.

Comment: This answer was already given by someone, but that person deleted it seems. The issue commented was that all websites get affected by this.